# Disable fsck in fstab for certain volume groups on 200 hosts

Tags: php, regex, bash, shell

There is a requirement in my environment to check **/etc/fstab** file and change last option to "**0 0**".

Example:

```
dev/datavg/ICC_ESB     /opt/data/ICC_ESB       ext3    defaults **1 1**
```

to

```
dev/datavg/ICC_ESB     /opt/data/ICC_ESB       ext3    defaults **0 0**
```

But the tricky one is, the changes need to be done only to **datavg or appvg.** 
in our environment we do have **rootvg and appvg.**

**Example:**

```
#### OS FS' should remain asis "1 1" untouched ##### 

/dev/rootvg/rootvol     /       ext3    defaults 1 1 
/dev/rootvg/usrvol      /usr    ext3    defaults 1 1 
/dev/rootvg/varvol      /var    ext3    defaults 1 1 
/dev/rootvg/optvol      /opt    ext3    defaults 1 1 
/dev/rootvg/tmpvol      /tmp    ext3    defaults 1 1 
/dev/rootvg/homevol     /home   ext3    defaults 1 1
```

---

```
#### But ALL the app/data FS's should be confirmed to have fsck turned off "**0 0**" ####

/dev/datavg/ICC_ESB     /opt/data/ICC_ESB       ext3    defaults 0 0 
/dev/datavg/InBox       /opt/data/InBox         ext3    defaults 0 0 
/dev/datavg/Pvds_Rma    /opt/data/Pvds_Rma      ext3    defaults 0 0 
/dev/datavg/Tivoli      /opt/data/Tivoli        ext3    defaults 0 0 
/dev/datavg/WASPShared  /opt/data/WASPShared    ext3    defaults 0 0 
/dev/datavg/WASSTShared /opt/data/WASSTShared   ext3    defaults 0 0 
/dev/datavg/WASUTShared /opt/data/WASUTShared   ext3    defaults 0 0
```

So far I've tried :

```
sed -e 's/^..//' -e 's/..$//' /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab-changes
```

I tried to remove the last lines in the fstab, and editing the fstab manually.

But I have more than 200 servers to do. Maybe someone could help me do that with sed or awk?

Update: Created an Shell script to find the FSCK Option.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat /etc/fstab | grep -v 'proc\|sda\|rootvg\|sysfs\|debugfs\|fd0\|.host\|nfshome:\|devpts' | awk '{print $6}') ; do
for n in $(cat /etc/fstab | grep -v 'proc\|sda\|rootvg\|sysfs\|debugfs\|fd0\|.host\|nfshome:\|devpts' | awk '{print $1}') ; do
if [[ "$i" != "0" ]] ; then
        echo "$n = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!"
else
        echo "The Non OS Partiton FSCK Complted Successfully !!!"
fi
done
done


Output:
/dev/repovg/lvol1 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/appvg/appvol-os = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/TEST12/TEST12 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/repovg/lvol1 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/appvg/appvol-os = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/TEST12/TEST12 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/repovg/lvol1 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/appvg/appvol-os = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/TEST12/TEST12 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
```

But, the results are repeating, is there any way to eliminate duplicate results ?

Comment: Why does this have the actionscript-3 tag?

Comment: btw, I'll remove the downvote as soon as you either remove that tag or mention why you have it in your question.

Comment: You also haven't mentioned what you've already tried.

Comment: i've removed the actionscript tag.

Comment: and I removed that downvote, though I still feel like I should downvote a question where you don't explain what you've tried

Comment: sed -e 's/^..//' -e 's/..$//' /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab-changes

i tried to remove the last lines in the fstab. and editing the fstab.

Comment: Nice! add that part to your question, it really enhances it.

Comment: yeah ! pardon me, since im new to this origination i dont have prior scripting knowledge. but i'm learning slowly day by day. By reading and understanding the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace datavg with appvg.

Oh, and publish what your device is so we don't buy it. This is a bad idea.

Comment: no, requirement is to replace the last value "1 1" to "0 0" only to datavg or appvg.